# Upgrade "Visual C++ 6" Solution/Project to "VS2022" Solution/Project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-c++-6

I work with VS2022 on Windows 11 Pro, and I have a Visual Studio C++ project from 2006 (contains DSW and DSP files): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1796/XListCtrl-A-custom-draw-list-control-with-subitem

After some reading, it seems that VS2022 is unable to handle the auto-upgrade and that auto-upgrade extends only up to VS2019. ***I prefer not to install VS2019 solely for this purpose, and I'm attempting to avoid the process of creating a restore point, installing VS2019, and then reverting to the restore point***. Is there an alternative method to auto-upgrade these DSW/DSP files so that the code can be opened and built using VS2022?

Comment: This is where make systems are much more handy; I much prefer using CMake with VS than using VS on its own... But, if that's not an option for you, and you don't want to use VS2019, then you will need to make a new Solutions in 2022 and copy over the files. Please note, that there's probably close to 0% chance that VC++6 code will compile in VS2022 without a lot of work.

Comment: @ChrisMM , it is not just "copy over the files" but also manually build all the configurations.

Comment: Do you really need a restore point and a backout? VS2019 is a 32-bit app and VS2022 is a 64-bit app - totally separate installations. Those of us that upgraded when a new version became available, have both versions installed and see no problem with that.

Comment: Another option is to fire-up a VM in either your home-lab/work-lab (free) or Azure (under $5 USD for the total time) for the ~1-2 hours you'll need to get a VC6 instance running.

Comment: @BoP was 2019 *only* 32 bit or did you have a choice?  Seems like a 64 bit version should have been available.

Comment: @MarkRansom VS2022 is the first _true_ 64-bit build of VS. Though, yes,, VS has had 64-bit components (like Roslyn, etc) going back to 2008, but they ran out-of-proc - so VS22022 is the first where `devenv.exe` itself is 64-bit)

Comment: Amit, that's unfortunate, but unavoidable, I think. If you have to go through the pain of this anyway, I'd seriously suggest using CMake (or similar, I just suggest CMake since it can generate VS solution files and its what I use). You can have different configurations setup differently using CMake

Comment: VC6 to VC22 is a heck of a version jump. I'd suggest installing VS 2019 on a VM rather than your currently working machine with VC 2022 on. Whilst I am fairly confident that higher versions can install OK over older ones I am less trusting that installing older MS compiler versions won;t inflict some sort of chaos on a working newer installation.

Comment: @ChrisMM is there anything that can make a CMake file from .dsw and .dsp files?  Seems like it would be possible but a quick search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I have no idea, but making all the CMake files isn't that difficult to do. It's mostly just tedious adding all the cpp/hpp files to it; can probably make a script to generate a lot of the CMakeList.txt files for you though.

Comment: @MartinBrown,  VS2019 and VS2022 coexist without conflicts. But, I only need VS2019 for a quick 5-minute conversion, and aside from that, it serves no purpose for me. On installation and uninstallation, residual data is left in the registry, which I prefer to avoid. That is why I prefer a restore point and a rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reluctantly, I created a restore point labeled X, installed VS2019 (just the "Desktop development with C++"), converted the solution (resulting in the conversion of all associated projects), and then reverted back to the X restore point. For cleanup: I deleted the DSW file and for each project: the DSP file, the conversion Log file.

Additional steps were necessary:

1. The `.vcxproj` and `.manifest` files had an `.xml` extension (For example: `XListCtrlDS.vcxproj.xml`) that required manual removal to enable loading by VS2022 from the solution.
2. In `Solution | Properties`, I had to create a `x64` configuration. I opened the `Configuration Manager...` and under `Active solution platform:` I selected `New... | x64`, opting to replicate settings from the x86 platform configuration (for a start). ***For extra:** Under `Edit...` I removed the `x86` configuration as it isn't relevant to my needs*.

***At this point when I open the solution, VS2022 open the solution, loads all the projects, but the projects are labeled as: `(Visual Studio 2019)`.***

*For each project: Properties (When `Configuration: All Configurations` and  `Platform: All Platforms`):*

3. Set `| General | Platform toolset` to `Visual Studio 2022 (v143)`. ***For extra:** I changed `C++ Language Standard` to `ISO C++20 Standard`*.
4. Edit `| C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories` I added: `..\XListCtrlLib` to let `stdafx.h` to be found.